# Creating a conditional dataframe column with recursive action in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, recursion

I have a df like below:

```html
time               sb       bn          bs
2020-04-07         True   False
2020-04-08         True   False
2020-04-09         True   False
2020-04-13        False   False
2020-04-14        False   False
2020-04-15        False   False
2020-04-16        False   False
2020-04-17        False   False
2020-04-20        False   False
2020-04-21        False    True
2020-04-22        False   False
2020-04-23        False   False
```

And condition like below:

```
if -> bn and !sb then True
else if -> bs[1] and sb then False
else -> bs[1]
```

And my code:

```
conditions = [
    (df["bn"] == True) & (df["sb"] == False),
    (df["bs"].shift(1) == True) & (df["sb"] == True)]
choices = ["True", "False"]
df["bs"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=df["bs"].shift(1))
```

I am getting an object not callable error. I think it is because of .shift(1). (I am using shift(1) for previous days data) The desired df with new bs column should be like:

```html
time              sb       bn          bs
2020-04-07        True     False       False
2020-04-08        True     False       False
2020-04-09        True     False       False
2020-04-13        False    False       False 
2020-04-14        False    False       False
2020-04-15        False    False       False
2020-04-16        False    False       False
2020-04-17        False    False       False
2020-04-20        False    False       False
2020-04-21        False    True        True
2020-04-22        False    False       True
2020-04-23        False    False       True
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Your logic is flawed to get that result. When you run the first mask you get a 'True' at column 'bs' and 2020-04-21. It's the only True in the column. When you shift 1 it moves to 2020-04-22, where sb and bn are false. So when you use the condition of True when bs shift 1 is Ture and sb is True, there are no rows that meet that condition. Not sure how you are trying to get the above df result, but it's not with that logic.

Comment: On a more technical note, `df["bs"].shift(1)` is a Series, but `np.select()` expects a scalar value as the `default` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need the previous value in the condition that defines the assignment, I don't see a better way than just using a `for` loop. Note that we need to handle the first row separately, because there is no previous value in that case. And you can shorten the conditional expressions a bit by setting all `bs` values to `False` initially.

```py
df['bs'] = np.repeat(False, len(df))

if df.bn[0] and not df.sb[0]:
    df.bs[0] = True

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df.bn[i] and not df.sb[i]:
        df.bs[i] = True
    else:
        if not (df.bs[i-1] and df.sb[i]):
            df.bs[i] = df.bs[i-1]          

df
```

```py
            sb      bn      bs
2020-04-07  True    False   False
2020-04-08  True    False   False
2020-04-09  True    False   False
2020-04-13  False   False   False
2020-04-14  False   False   False
2020-04-15  False   False   False
2020-04-16  False   False   False
2020-04-17  False   False   False
2020-04-20  False   False   False
2020-04-21  False   True    True
2020-04-22  False   False   True
2020-04-23  False   False   True
```

Comment: Ame, "np.select() expects a scalar value as the default parameter" this is a neat info. Thank you for the path